# Using write method to save a picture file in Java

Tags: java, image, directory, save

I need to save a picture object into the working directory with a specific file name using the write method. Here's my code:

```
  public void storePhotos(String directory){

    for(int i = 0; i < labelledPhotos.length; i++){
      Picture currentPhoto = new Picture(labelledPhotos[i].getLabelledPhoto());

      String fileName = directory + "/" + labelledPhotos[i].getYear() + "_" + labelledPhotos[i].getCategory() + "_" +  labelledPhotos[i].getId() + ".jpg";    
      currentPhoto.write(fileName);

    }
```

The user is suppose to input the director as the parameter and I need to save the image to the directory. For some reason the write method isn't saving it. If I hard code in the directory into the write parameter like:

```
currentPhoto.write("pic.jpg");
```

then the photo gets saved into directory. So I know its something wrong with the `String` `fileName` and how it gets passed into the write method, but I'm not sure what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `Picture`?  If you're using non-standard libraries, you might like to highlight the name of the API or provide a link to the JavaDocs...

Comment: Certainly it's saving the file, unless you're getting an `IOException` you haven't told us about, e.g. `FileNotFoundException.`

Comment: I'm using the Dr.Java library for my course and Picture is a class within the library.

I don't think it's actually saving the file, I've tried searching for it on my computer but haven't found anything. And when I run the program, everything compiles and runs, no errors or exceptions.